# concatenate variable + selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I concatenate the second line:

```
 var newLink = $(this).attr("id")

 $("section").load( newLink + "section > *"); // this is not working
```

**newLink** is the variable and **"section > *"** is the selector.thx

Comment: What is the value of `newlinnk`?

Comment: why a call to load()? Isn't that an Ajax method?

Comment: some link, like: index html, but it dosent matter because is going to change all the time... or does it?

Comment: @Noobest It matters. Because CSS selector might need `#` or maybe not in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put space before "section", otherwise CSS selector is incorrect (assuming that there is child `section` tag within whatever tag `newLink` points to):

```
var newLink = $(this).attr("id")
$("section").load(newLink + " section > *");
```

Note, that you might want to prepend newLink with `#` if you want ID selector.

Comment: also a "#" in front of newLink : $("section").load('#' + newLink + " section > *");

Comment: @jlowcs Right, I'm just not sure OP wants id selector, or something else. `newLink` can be `div` or something.

Comment: I just needed to add the space, so simple yet so difficult. Thx.